# Using Generics with LinqToObjects and NOT IN

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I want to turn the follow function into a Lambda.  After working on it for  45 minutes, I decided to go old school.  How would one do this with a Lambda?

```
public static void NotIn<T>(List<T> inListOne, List<T> notInListTwo,ref List<T> resultList)
{

   resultList = new List<T>();

   foreach (T item in inListOne)
   {
      if (notInListTwo.Contains(item))
      {
          resultList.Add(item);
      }
   }              
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = inListOne.Except(notInListTwo).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks,

Final answer:


        public static void NotIn<T>(List<T> inListOne, List<T> notInListTwo, ref List<T> resultList)
        {
            resultList = inListOne.Except(notInListTwo).ToList();
        }

Comment: @user434290, why not make resultList be the return value instead of using a ref argument ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [Except extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx):

```
listOne.Except(listTwo);
```